# native websocket api NodeJS for larger messages?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, buffer, rfc

I was following an [article about writing a socket server from scratch](https://medium.com/hackernoon/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8), and its mostly working with small frames / packages, but when I try to send about 2kb of data, I get this error:
.

```
internal/buffer.js:77
  throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(type || 'offset',
  ^
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 7. Receive
d 8
    at boundsError (internal/buffer.js:77:9)
    at Buffer.readUInt8 (internal/buffer.js:243:5)
    at pm (/home/users/me/main.js:277:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/users/me/main.js:149:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
```

Here's my server code (some details were changed for security, but here it is in its entirety for the line numbers etc.) but the relevant part here is the function pm [=parseMessage](towards the bottom):

```
let http = require('http'),
    ch   = require("child_process"),
    crypto = require("crypto"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    password = fs.readFileSync(“./secretPasswordFile.txt”),
    callbacks = {
    
    CHANGEDforSecUrITY(m, cs) {
        if(m.password === password) {
            if(m.command) {
                try {
                    cs.my = ch.exec(
                        m.command,
                        (
                            err,
                            stdout,
                            stderr
                        ) => {
                            cs.write(ans(s({
                                err,
                                stdout,
                                stderr
                            })));
                        }
                    );
                } catch(e) {
                    cs.write(ans(
                        s({
                            error: e.toString()
                        })
                    ))
                }
            }
            if(m.exit) {
                console.log("LOL", cs.my);
                if(cs.my && typeof cs.my.kill === "function") {
                    cs.my.kill();
                    console.log(cs.my, "DID?");
                }
            }
            cs.write(
                ans(
                    s({
                    hi: 2,
                    youSaid:m
                }))
                
            
            )
        } else {
            cs.write(ans(s({
                hey: "wrong password!!"
            })))
        }

        
        console.log("hi!",m)
    }
    },
    banned = [
    "61.19.71.84"
    ],
    server = http.createServer(
    (q,r)=> {
        if(banned.includes(q.connection.remoteAddress)) {
            r.end("Hey man, " + q.connection.remoteAddress, 
                "I know you're there!!");
        } else {
            ch.exec(`sudo "$(which node)" -p "console.log(4)"`)
            console.log(q.url)
            console.log(q.connection.remoteAddress,q.connection.remotePort)        
            let path = q.url.substring(1)
            q.url == "/" && 
                (path = "index.html")
            q.url == "/secret" &&
                (path = "../main.js")
            fs.readFile(
                "./static/" + path,
                (er, f) => {
                    if(er) {
                        r.end("<h2>404!!</h2>");    
            
                    } else {
                        r.end(f);
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
    )
server.listen(
    process.env.PORT || 80, 
    c=> {
        console.log(c,"helo!!!")
        server.on("upgrade", (req, socket) => {
            if(req.headers["upgrade"] !== "websocket") {
                socket.end("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
                return;
            }
            
            let key = req.headers["sec-websocket-key"];
            if(key) {
                let hash = gav(key)
                let headers = [
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake",
                    "Upgrade: WebSocket",
                    "Connection: Upgrade",
                    `Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ${hash}`
                ];
                let protocol = req.headers[
                    "sec-websocket-protocol"
                ];
                let protocols = (
                    protocol &&
                    protocol.split(",")
                    .map(s => s.trim())
                    || []
                );
                protocols.includes("json") &&
                    headers
                    .push("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: json");
                let headersStr = (
                    headers.join("\r\n") + 
                    "\r\n\r\n"

                
                )


                console.log(
                    "Stuff happening",
                    req.headers,
                    headersStr
                );
                fs.writeFileSync("static/logs.txt",headersStr);
                socket.write(
                    headersStr
                );


                socket.write(ans(JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        hello: "world!!!"
                    }
                )))

            }
            
            socket.on("data", buf => {
                let msg = pm(buf);
                console.log("HEY MAN!",msg)
                if(msg) {
                    console.log("GOT!",msg);
                    for(let k in msg) {
                        if(callbacks[k]) {
                            callbacks[k](
                                msg[k],
                                socket
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("nope");
                }
            });
        });

    }
)

function pm(buf) {
    /*
     *structure of first byte:
         1: if its the last frame in buffer
         2 - 4: reserved bits
         5 - 8: a number which shows what type of message it is. Chart:

             "0": means we continue
             "1": means this frame contains text
             "2": means this is binary
             "0011"(3) - "0111" (11): reserved values
             "1000"(8): means connection closed
             "1001"(9): ping (checking for response)
             "1010"(10): pong (response verified)
             "1010"(11) - "1111"(15): reserved for "control" frames
     structure of second byte:
        1: is it "masked"
        2 - 8: length of payload, if less than 126.
            if 126, 2 additional bytes are added
            if 127 (or more), 6 additional bytes added (total 8)

     * */
    const myFirstByte = buf.readUInt8(0);

    const isThisFinalFrame = isset(myFirstByte,7) //first bit

    const [
        reserved1,
        reserved2,
        reserved3
    ] = [
        isset(myFirstByte, 6),
        isset(myFirstByte, 5),
        isset(myFirstByte, 4) //reserved bits 
    ]
    
    const opcode = myFirstByte & parseInt("1111",2); //checks last 4 bits

    //check if closed connection ("1000"(8))
    if(opcode == parseInt("1000", 2))
        return null; //shows that connection closed

    //look for text frame ("0001"(1))
    if(opcode == parseInt("0001",2)) {
        const theSecondByte = buf.readUInt8(1);

        const isMasked = isset(theSecondByte, 7) //1st bit from left side
        
        let currentByteOffset = 2; //we are theSecondByte now, so 2

        let payloadLength = theSecondByte & 127; //chcek up to 7 bits

        if(payloadLength > 125) {
            if(payloadLength === 126) {
                payloadLength = buf.readUInt16BE(
                    currentByteOffset
                ) //read next two bytes from position
                currentByteOffset += 2; //now we left off at 
                //the fourth byte, so thats where we are
            
            } else {
                //if only the second byte is full,
                //that shows that there are 6 more 
                //bytes to hold the length 
                const right = buf.readUInt32BE(
                    currentByteOffset
                );
                const left = buf.readUInt32BE(
                    currentByteOffset + 4 //the 8th byte ??
                );

                throw new Error("brutal " + currentByteOffset);

            }
        }

        //if we have masking byte set to 1, get masking key
        //
        //
    

        //now that we have the lengths
        //and possible masks, read the rest 
        //of the bytes, for actual data
        const data = Buffer.alloc(payloadLength); 

        if(isMasked) {
            //can't just copy it,
            //have to do some stuff with
            //the masking key and this thing called
            //"XOR" to the data. Complicated
            //formulas, llook into later
            //
            let maskingBytes = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
            buf.copy(
                maskingBytes,
                0,
                currentByteOffset,
                currentByteOffset + 4
            );
            currentByteOffset += 4;
            for(
                let i = 0;
                i < payloadLength;
                ++i
            ) {
 
                const source = buf.readUInt8(
                    currentByteOffset++
                );

                //now mask the source with masking byte
                data.writeUInt8(
                    source ^ maskingBytes[i & 3],
                    i
                );
            }
        } else {
            //just copy bytes directly to our buffer
            buf.copy(
                data,
                0,
                currentByteOffset++
            );
        }

        //at this point we have the actual data, so make a json
        //
        const json = data.toString("utf8");
        return p(json);
    } else {
        return "LOL IDK?!";
    }
}

function p(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch(e){
        return str
    }
}

function s(ob) {
    try {
        return JSON.stringify(ob);
    } catch(e) {
        return e.toString();
    }
}

function ans(str) {
    const byteLength = Buffer.byteLength(str);

    const lengthByteCount = byteLength < 126 ? 0 : 2;
    const payloadLength = lengthByteCount === 0 ? byteLength : 126;

    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(
        2 +
        lengthByteCount + 
        byteLength
    );

    buffer.writeUInt8(
        parseInt("10000001",2), //opcode is "1", at firstbyte
        0
    );

    buffer.writeUInt8(payloadLength, 1); //at second byte

    let currentByteOffset = 2; //already wrote second byte by now

    if(lengthByteCount > 0) {
        buffer.writeUInt16BE(
            byteLength,
            2 //more length at 3rd byte position
        );
        currentByteOffset += lengthByteCount; //which is 2 more bytes
        //of length, since not supporting more than that
    }

    buffer.write(str, currentByteOffset); //the rest of the bytes
    //are the actual data, see chart in function pm
    //
    return buffer;
}

function gav(ak) {
    return crypto
    .createHash("sha1")
    .update(ak +'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', "binary")
    .digest("base64")
}

function isset(b, k) {
    return !!(
        b >>> k & 1
    )
}
```

Given that this error does **not** happen with smaller packets, I'm taking an educated guess that this is due to the limitations of the code here, as mentioned in the [offical RFC documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.4):

> 5.4.  Fragmentation
>
> The primary purpose of fragmentation is to allow sending a message
> that is of unknown size when the message is started without having to
> buffer that message.  If messages couldn't be fragmented, then an
> endpoint would have to buffer the entire message so its length could
> be counted before the first byte is sent.  With fragmentation, a
> server or intermediary may choose a reasonable size buffer and, when
> the buffer is full, write a fragment to the network.
>
> A secondary use-case for fragmentation is for multiplexing, where
> it    is not desirable for a large message on one logical channel to
> monopolize the output channel, so the multiplexing needs to be free to
> split the message into smaller fragments to better share the    output
> channel.  (Note that the multiplexing extension is not    described in
> this document.)
>
> Unless specified otherwise by an extension, frames have no semantic
> meaning.  An intermediary might coalesce and/or split frames, if no
> extensions were negotiated by the client and the server or if some
> extensions were negotiated, but the intermediary understood all the
> extensions negotiated and knows how to coalesce and/or split frames
> in the presence of these extensions.  One implication of this is that
> in absence of extensions, senders and receivers must not depend on
> the presence of specific frame boundaries.
>
> The following rules apply to fragmentation:
>
> o  An unfragmented message consists of a single frame with the FIN
> bit set (Section 5.2) and an opcode other than 0.
>
> o  A fragmented message consists of a single frame with the FIN bit
> clear and an opcode other than 0, followed by zero or more frames
> with the FIN bit clear and the opcode set to 0, and terminated by
> a single frame with the FIN bit set and an opcode of 0.  A
> fragmented message is conceptually equivalent to a single larger
> message whose payload is equal to the concatenation of the
> payloads of the fragments in order; however, in the presence of
> extensions, this may not hold true as the extension defines the
> interpretation of the "Extension data" present.  For instance,
> "Extension data" may only be present at the beginning of the first
> fragment and apply to subsequent fragments, or there may be
> "Extension data" present in each of the fragments that applies
> only to that particular fragment.  In the absence of "Extension
> data", the following example demonstrates how fragmentation works.
>
> ```
>   EXAMPLE: For a text message sent as three fragments, the first
>   fragment would have an opcode of 0x1 and a FIN bit clear, the
>   second fragment would have an opcode of 0x0 and a FIN bit clear,
>   and the third fragment would have an opcode of 0x0 and a FIN bit
>   that is set.
> ```
>
> o  Control frames (see Section 5.5) MAY be injected in the middle
> of
> a fragmented message.  Control frames themselves MUST NOT be
> fragmented.
>
> o  Message fragments MUST be delivered to the recipient in the
> order
> sent by the sender. o  The fragments of one message MUST NOT be interleaved between the
> fragments of another message unless an extension has been
> negotiated that can interpret the interleaving.
>
> o  An endpoint MUST be capable of handling control frames in the
> middle of a fragmented message.
>
> o  A sender MAY create fragments of any size for non-control
> messages.
>
> o  Clients and servers MUST support receiving both fragmented and
> unfragmented messages.
>
> o  As control frames cannot be fragmented, an intermediary MUST NOT
> attempt to change the fragmentation of a control frame.
>
> o  An intermediary MUST NOT change the fragmentation of a message
> if
> any reserved bit values are used and the meaning of these values
> is not known to the intermediary.
>
> o  An intermediary MUST NOT change the fragmentation of any message
> in the context of a connection where extensions have been
> negotiated and the intermediary is not aware of the semantics of
> the negotiated extensions.  Similarly, an intermediary that didn't
> see the WebSocket handshake (and wasn't notified about its
> content) that resulted in a WebSocket connection MUST NOT change
> the fragmentation of any message of such connection.
>
> o  As a consequence of these rules, all fragments of a message are
> of
> the same type, as set by the first fragment's opcode.  Since
> control frames cannot be fragmented, the type for all fragments in
> a message MUST be either text, binary, or one of the reserved
> opcodes.
>
> NOTE: If control frames could not be interjected, the latency of a
> ping, for example, would be very long if behind a large message.
> Hence, the requirement of handling control frames in the middle of a
> fragmented message.
>
> IMPLEMENTATION NOTE: In the absence of any extension, a receiver
> doesn't have to buffer the whole frame in order to process it.  For
> example, if a streaming API is used, a part of a frame can be
> delivered to the application.  However, note that this assumption
> might not hold true for all future WebSocket extensions.

In the words of [the article above](https://medium.com/hackernoon/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8#a760):

> Alignment of Node.js socket buffers with WebSocket message frames
>
> Node.js socket data (I’m talking about net.Socket in this case, not
> WebSockets) is received in buffered chunks. These are split apart with
> no regard for where your WebSocket frames begin or end!
>
> What this means is that if your server is receiving large messages
> fragmented into multiple WebSocket frames, or receiving large numbers
> of messages in rapid succession, there’s no guarantee that each data
> buffer received by the Node.js socket will align with the start and
> end of the byte data that makes up a given frame.
>
> So, as you’re parsing each buffer received by the socket, you’ll need
> to keep track of where one frame ends and where the next begins.
> You’ll need to be sure that you’ve received all of the bytes of data
> for a frame — before you can safely consume that frame’s data.
>
> It may be that one frame ends midway through the same buffer in which
> the next frame begins. It also may be that a frame is split across
> several buffers that will be received in succession.
>
> The following diagram is an exaggerated illustration of the issue. In
> most cases, frames tend to fit inside a buffer. Due to the way the
> data arrives, you’ll often find that a frame will start and end in
> line with the start and end of the socket buffer. But this can’t be
> relied upon in all cases, and must be considered during
> implementation. [image] This can take
> some work to get right.
>
> For the basic implementation that follows below, I have skipped any
> code for handling large messages or messages split across multiple
> frames.

So my problem here is that the article skipped the fragmentation code, which is kind of what I need to know...  but [in that RFC documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.6), some examples of fragmentated and unfragmented packets are given:

> 5.6.  Data Frames
>
> Data frames (e.g., non-control frames) are identified by opcodes
> where the most significant bit of the opcode is 0.  Currently defined
> opcodes for data frames include 0x1 (Text), 0x2 (Binary).  Opcodes
> 0x3-0x7 are reserved for further non-control frames yet to be
> defined.
>
> Data frames carry application-layer and/or extension-layer data.
> The    opcode determines the interpretation of the data:
>
> Text
>
> ```
>   The "Payload data" is text data encoded as UTF-8.  Note that a
>   particular text frame might include a partial UTF-8 sequence;
>   however, the whole message MUST contain valid UTF-8.  Invalid
>   UTF-8 in reassembled messages is handled as described in
>   Section 8.1.
> ```
>
> Binary
>
> ```
>   The "Payload data" is arbitrary binary data whose interpretation
>   is solely up to the application layer.
> ```
>
> 5.7.  Examples
>
> o  A single-frame unmasked text message
>
> ```
>   *  0x81 0x05 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f (contains "Hello")
> ```
>
> o  A single-frame masked text message
>
> ```
>   *  0x81 0x85 0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d 0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58
>      (contains "Hello")
> ```
>
> o  A fragmented unmasked text message
>
> ```
>   *  0x01 0x03 0x48 0x65 0x6c (contains "Hel")
>
>   *  0x80 0x02 0x6c 0x6f (contains "lo")
> ```
>
> o  Unmasked Ping request and masked Ping response
>
> ```
>   *  0x89 0x05 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f (contains a body of "Hello",
>      but the contents of the body are arbitrary)
>
>   *  0x8a 0x85 0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d 0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58
>      (contains a body of "Hello", matching the body of the ping)
> ```
>
> o  256 bytes binary message in a single unmasked frame
>
> ```
>   *  0x82 0x7E 0x0100 [256 bytes of binary data]
> ```
>
> o  64KiB binary message in a single unmasked frame
>
> ```
>   *  0x82 0x7F 0x0000000000010000 [65536 bytes of binary data]
> ```

So it would appear that is an example of a fragment.

Also [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-6.2) seems relevant:

> 6.2.  Receiving Data
>
> To receive WebSocket data, an endpoint listens on the underlying
> network connection.  Incoming data MUST be parsed as WebSocket frames
> as defined in Section 5.2.  If a control frame (Section 5.5) is
> received, the frame MUST be handled as defined by Section 5.5.  Upon
> receiving a data frame (Section 5.6), the endpoint MUST note the
> /type/ of the data as defined by the opcode (frame-opcode) from
> Section 5.2.  The "Application data" from this frame is defined as
> the /data/ of the message.  **If the frame comprises an unfragmented
>
> message (Section 5.4), it is said that *A WebSocket Message Has Been
>
> Received* with type /type/ and data /data/.  If the frame is part of
>
> a fragmented message, the "Application data" of the subsequent data
>
> frames is concatenated to form the /data/.  When the last fragment is
> received as indicated by the FIN bit (frame-fin), it is said that *A
>
> WebSocket Message Has Been Received* with data /data/ (comprised of
>
> the concatenation of the "Application data" of the fragments) and type
> /type/ (noted from the first frame of the fragmented message).
>
> Subsequent data frames MUST be interpreted as belonging to a new
>
> WebSocket message.**
>
> Extensions (Section 9) MAY change the semantics of how data is
> read,    specifically including what comprises a message boundary.
> Extensions, in addition to adding "Extension data" before the
> "Application data" in a payload, MAY also modify the "Application
> data" (such as by compressing it).

The problem:

I don't know how to check for fragments and line them up with the node buffers, as mentioned in the article, I'm only able to read very small buffer amounts.

**How can I parse larger data chunks using the fragmentation methods mentioned in the RFC documentation and the lining-up of nodeJS buffers alluded to** (but not explained) **in the article?**

Comment: Sending and accepting large messages is generally discouraged, due to making such services prone to [denial-of-service attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). Without message size limitations in place, a malicious third party could overload your service by sending large messages over the websocket connection.

Comment: @attilla I can add limitations once I know how to even begin to send larger messages, plus was the websocket protocol built to only send 5kb messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across your question when I was working on my own "pure NodeJs WebSocket server". All worked fine for payloads less than 1-2 KiB. When I was trying to send more, but still within [64 KiB - 1] limit (16 bit payload length), it randomly blow up the server with ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE error.

**Side note:** https://medium.com/hackernoon/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8 "Implementing a WebSocket server with Node.js" by Srushtika Neelakantam is excellent article! Before I found it the WebSocket was alwas a black box to me. She described very simple and easy to understand implementation of WebSocket client/server from scratch. Unfortunately it lacks (on purpose to not make article hard) support for larger payloads and buffers alignment. I just wanted to give Srushtika Neelakantam credit because without her article I would never write my own pure NodeJs WebSocket server.

The solution described in the article fails only because the NodeJs buffer is simply over and there are no more bytes to read but the function's logic expects more bytes. You end with ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE error. Code simply wants to read bytes that are not yet available but will be available in next 'data' event.

The solution to this problem is simply check if the next byte that you want to read from buffer is really available. As long as there are bytes you are fine. The challenge starts when there to less bytes or to much bytes. In order to be be more flexible the function that parses buffer should return not only payload but pair: payload and bufferRemainingBytes. It will allow to concat the buffers in the main data event handler.

We need to handle three cases:

1. When there is exactly the right amount of bytes in the buffer to build valid WebSocket frame we return
   { payload: payloadFromValidWebSocketFrame, bufferRemainingBytes: Buffer.alloc(0) }
2. When there are enough bytes to build valid WebSocket but still there are few left in the buffer we return
   { payload: payloadFromValidWebSocketFrame, bufferRemainingBytes: bufferBytesAfterValidWebSocketFrame }

   This case also forces us to wrap all getParsedBuffer calls with a do-while loop. The bufferRemainingBytes could still contain second (or third, or more) valid WebSocket frame. We need to parse them all in currently processed socket data event.
3. When there are not enough bytes to build valid WebSocket frame we return empty payload and entire buffer as bufferRemainingBytes
   { payload: null, bufferRemainingBytes: buffer }

How to merge buffers together with bufferRemainingBytes in the subsequent socket data events? Here is the code:

```js
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket) => {
  let bufferToParse = Buffer.alloc(0); // at the beginning we just start with 0 bytes

  // .........

  socket.on('data', buffer => {
    let parsedBuffer;

    // concat 'past' bytes with the 'current' bytes
    bufferToParse = Buffer.concat([bufferToParse, buffer]);

    do {
      parsedBuffer = getParsedBuffer(bufferToParse);

      // the output of the debugBuffer calls will be on the screenshot later
      debugBuffer('buffer', buffer);
      debugBuffer('bufferToParse', bufferToParse);
      debugBuffer('parsedBuffer.payload', parsedBuffer.payload);
      debugBuffer('parsedBuffer.bufferRemainingBytes', parsedBuffer.bufferRemainingBytes);

      bufferToParse = parsedBuffer.bufferRemainingBytes;

      if (parsedBuffer.payload) {
        // .........
        // handle the payload as you like, for example send to other sockets
      }
    } while (parsedBuffer.payload && parsedBuffer.bufferRemainingBytes.length);

    console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------\n');
  });

  // .........
});
```

Here is how my getParsedBuffer function looks like(it was called parseMessage in the article):

```js
const getParsedBuffer = buffer => {
  // .........
  
  // whenever I want to read X bytes I simply check if I really can read X bytes
  if (currentOffset + 2 > buffer.length) {
    return { payload: null, bufferRemainingBytes: buffer };
  }
  payloadLength = buffer.readUInt16BE(currentOffset);
  currentOffset += 2;
  
  // .........
  
  // in 99% of cases this will prevent the ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE error to happen
  if (currentOffset + payloadLength > buffer.length) {
    console.log('[misalignment between WebSocket frame and NodeJs Buffer]\n');
    return { payload: null, bufferRemainingBytes: buffer };
  }

  payload = Buffer.alloc(payloadLength);

  if (isMasked) {
    // ......... I skip masked code as it's too long and not masked shows the idea same way
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < payloadLength; i++) {
      payload.writeUInt8(buffer.readUInt8(currentOffset++), i);
    }
  }

  // it could also happen at this point that we already have a valid WebSocket payload
  // but there are still some bytes remaining in the buffer
  // we need to copy all unused bytes and return them as bufferRemainingBytes
  bufferRemainingBytes = Buffer.alloc(buffer.length - currentOffset);
  //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this value could be >= 0
  for (let i = 0; i < bufferRemainingBytes.length; i++) {
    bufferRemainingBytes.writeUInt8(buffer.readUInt8(currentOffset++), i);
  }

  return { payload, bufferRemainingBytes };
}
```

---

Real life test of the described solution (64 KiB - 1 bytes):

[image: server log]

---

**In short - the above solution should work fine with payloads up to [64 KiB - 1] bytes. It's written entirely in pure NodeJs without any external library. I guess that is what you were looking for in your project ;)**

Please find below the links to full version of my Binary Broadcast App on GitHub gist:

- server https://gist.github.com/robertrypula/b813ffe23a9489bae1b677f1608676c8
- client https://gist.github.com/robertrypula/f8da8f89819068a97bef4f27d04ad5b7

For some time (before I deploy the updated app with more features) the live demo of above's gist can be found here:

http://sndu.pl - let's send you the file

Comment: yes thank you, but how can we get more than 64kb?

Comment: Then you need to split your data into packets with some header (like first 4 bytes encodes offset of the 64 KiB - 4 bytes block of data). On the sending side you split and on the receiving side you merge.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip, is there any kind of working example code for this?

Answer (score 0):

this is not perfect answer but an approach. this is how i would do what you are trying to do. i m writing pseudo code just to save time ;)

first i will be creating a custom object to communicate :

```
class Request {
    id?: string; // unique id of the request, same request id can be used to continue a requst or to reply to a request
    api?: string; // the request type i.e. what kind of request it is or how do you want this data to be used like a client can perform multiple operations on server like API_AUTH or API_CREATE_FILE etc.
    complete?: boolean; // this is a flag if the request is complete or it needs to be added to the queue to wait for more data
    error?: boolean; // this flag ll be helpful in request replies when the server has processed the request for an api and wants to respond with error or success
    message?: string; // just sample message that can be shown or helpful raw note for the developer to debug
    data?: any; // this is the actual data being sent
}
```

now for communicating between both the sides(i m taking server client approach in this example) we ll use this object.

now here is some pseudo code about how to process on server

```
class Server {
    requestQueue: Map<string, Request> = new Map();

    onRequestReceived(request: Request) {
        if(request !== undefined){
            switch(request.api){
                case "API_LONG_DATA": 
                    if(this.requestQueue.get(request.id) !== undefined){
                        if(request.complete){
                            // add this data to the requests in the querue, process the request and remove it from the queue
                        }else{
                            // add data to the request in the queue and resave it to the map
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(request.complete){
                            // process your request here
                        }else{
                            // add this request to queue
                        }
                    }
                break;
                case "API_AUTH": 
                    // just a sample api
                break;
            }
        }else{
            // respond with error
        }
    }
}
```

this is easier than playing with buffers i believe and even i have used this approach a lot many times and sending large chunk of data is not a good practice because it can be used by someone to exploit your resources and it might fail in low networks.

so hope you get some hints from my approach ;)

**UPDATE[full implementation]**

first we need websoket package so

`npm install websocket`

now this is how we create websocket server in node.js using websocket package and process incoming requests

`server.ts`

```
import { WebSocketServer } from 'websocket';
import * as http from 'http';

// this is the request data object which ll serve as a common data entity that both server and client are aware of
class Request {
    id?: string; // unique id of the request, same request id can be used to continue a requst or to reply to a request
    api?: string; // the request type i.e. what kind of request it is or how do you want this data to be used like a client can perform multiple operations on server like API_AUTH or API_CREATE_FILE etc.
    complete?: boolean; // this is a flag if the request is complete or it needs to be added to the queue to wait for more data
    error?: boolean; // this flag ll be helpful in request replies when the server has processed the request for an api and wants to respond with error or success
    message?: string; // just sample message that can be shown or helpful raw note for the developer to debug
    data?: any; // this is the actual data being sent
}

// this is optional if you want to show 404 on the page

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});
 
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
 
function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}
 
wsServer.on('request', (request) => {
    if (originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
        const connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
        // this is the request queue is there are any heavy request which cant fit into one request
        const requestQueue: Map<string, Request> = new Map();

        connection.on('message', (message) => {
            // i consider that the data being sent to server is utf8 string
            if (message.type === 'utf8') {
                // here we construct the request object from incoming data
                const request: Request = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
                // here we process the request
                switch(request.api){
                case "API_LONG_DATA": 
                        if(requestQueue.get(request.id) !== undefined){
                            if(request.complete){
                                // add this data to the requests in the querue, process the request and remove it from the queue
                            }else{
                                // add data to the request in the queue and resave it to the map
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(request.complete){
                                // process your request here
                            }else{
                                // add this request to queue
                            }
                        }
                    break;
                    case "API_AUTH": 
                        // just a sample api
                    break;
                }
            }else{
                // handle other data types
            }
        });

        connection.on('close', (reasonCode, description) => {
            // a connection as closed do cleanup here
        });
    }else{
      // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      request.reject();
    }
});
```

here is the way you send data from client

`client.ts`

```
import { WebSocketClient } from 'websocket';

// this is the request data object which ll serve as a common data entity that both server and client are aware of
class Request {
    id?: string; // unique id of the request, same request id can be used to continue a requst or to reply to a request
    api?: string; // the request type i.e. what kind of request it is or how do you want this data to be used like a client can perform multiple operations on server like API_AUTH or API_CREATE_FILE etc.
    complete?: boolean; // this is a flag if the request is complete or it needs to be added to the queue to wait for more data
    error?: boolean; // this flag ll be helpful in request replies when the server has processed the request for an api and wants to respond with error or success
    message?: string; // just sample message that can be shown or helpful raw note for the developer to debug
    data?: any; // this is the actual data being sent
}

const client = new WebSocketClient();
 
client.on('connectFailed', (error) => {
    // handle error when connection failed
});
 
client.on('connect', (connection) => {
    connection.on('error', (error)=> {
        // handle when some error occurs in existing connection
    });
    connection.on('close', () => {
        // connection closed
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        // i m condsidering we are using utf8 data to communicate
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            // here we parse request object
            const request: Request = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            // here you can handle the request object 
        }else{
            // handle other data types
        }
    });

    // here you start communicating with the server

    // example 1. normal requst
    const authRequest: Request = {
        id: "auth_request_id",
        api: "API_AUTH",
        complete: true,
        data: {
            user: "testUser",
            pass: "testUserPass"
        }
    }
    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(authRequest));

    // example 2. long data request
    const longRequestChunk1: Request = {
        id: "long_chunck_request_id",
        api: "API_LONG_CHUNCK",
        complete: false, // observer this flag. as this is the first part of the chunk so this needs to be added to the queue on server
        data: "..." // path one of long data
    }
    const longRequestChunk2: Request = {
        id: "long_chunck_request_id", // request id must be the same
        api: "API_LONG_CHUNCK", // same api
        complete: true, // as this is the last part of the chunk so this flag is true
        data: "..." // path one of long data
    }
    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(longRequestChunk1));
    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(longRequestChunk2));
    
});
 
client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');
```

i can explain it furthure if you want ;)

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question, how can I use this to create a websocket protocol for scratch using the maximum length that websockets allow?

Comment: @bluejayke for using this you must have basic knowlege about websockets

Comment: @bluejayke protocol is any set of rules that both parties agree on. in my answer both client and server know the structure of request object. i was expecting you to  understand that its a raw implementation just to give you an approach

Comment: @bluejayke i m updating the answer with some code from the tutorial you followed so that you can understand how you can use this approach

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to do, you start out `import { WebSocketServer } from 'websocket';` and `first we need websoket package so

npm install websocket`, if I wanted to use a library I could find a library on my own and read the instructions, the entire point of this question was how to implement websockets *without any library at all*, specifically how to link the raw socket buffers to the websocket buffers and align them to get the data, low level byte analyzing is what I'm trying to figure out how to do

Comment: Unless you want to make your own wheel :) thanks for the answer though, its good for getting the idea behind it